# How to install Selenium and Nokogiri for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, nokogiri, ruby-1.9.3

I have just installed Ruby 1.9.3 on my Windows 7 PC. Now I am looking for some automation script to write. But for that I have to install the below, but how do I install them?

- Selenium
- NokoGiri
- Capybara

My Ruby version is installed in the directory- `C:\Ruby193`. To run the Ruby command from the command prompt, should I need to add anything to the `PATH` variable?

***Error***

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\peter>cd..

C:\Users>cd..

C:\>cd C:\Ruby193

C:\Ruby193>ruby
'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Ruby193>gem install nokogiri
'gem' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Ruby193>
```

Comment: how will i check if all the packages are installed properly or not?

Comment: I am getting an error,please help me

Comment: How have you installed Ruby? What tool/instructions have you used for that?

Comment: @AndreyBotalov using ruby installer! can you tell me how to check if `nokogiri` is installed or not?

Comment: Run `gem list`. It should be there if it's installed

Comment: i followed [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJlfVjGt6Hg) to install ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gem install nokogiri
```

You can do the same with the other gems.

Comment: For starters in your project directory?

Comment: should I need to add anything to the system `PATH`variable?

Comment: I just installed Ruby from its set up file, but i didn't run `  gem update --system`. is it needed?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to update the environment variable PATH, pointing towards your ruby's bin folder.
Then you would have to install DevKit as you are on windows.
From here you can download DevKit : http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/.

After all this is installed successfully,then only you will be able to install any gem.